# Are Jungian ideas of enantiodromia supported by research

Tags: jung

Jung describes the process of [enantiodromia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiodromia) as "this characteristic phenomenon practically always occurs when an extreme, one-sided tendency dominates conscious life; in time an equally powerful counterposition is built up which first inhibits the conscious performance and subsequently breaks through the conscious control."

Is there research that supports that notion?